# Error pide número con DO WHILE hasta que se introduzca entero

Tags: java

El siguinte programa pide entrada de datos por teclado hasta que se introduzca un entero. EL while parece que da error.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Programa {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //PIDE HASTA INTRODUCIR NÚMERO ENTERO
      do{
          System.out.println("Introduce un numero:");
          Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
      } while (!teclado.hasNextInt())
        //SI ES ENTERO TOMA EL DATO EN NUM
      int num = teclado.nextInt();
      System.out.println(num);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hice algunos cambios:

```
  import java.util.*;
  public class Programa {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     //PIDE HASTA INTRODUCIR NÚMERO ENTERO
     Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
     do{
        System.out.println("Introduce un numero:");
        teclado.next();
       }while(!teclado.hasNextInt());
       //SI ES ENTERO TOMA EL DATO EN NUM
       int num = teclado.nextInt();
       System.out.println(num);
      }
```